# How to migrate <dynamic> from ibatis to mybatis

Tags: spring, dynamic, mybatis, ibatis

I wish to change this from ibatis 2.0

```
    UPDATE AccountData SET
        StatisticAccountingUnits=   <isNotNull property="statisticAccountingUnits">#statisticAccountingUnits#</isNotNull>   <isNull property="statisticAccountingUnits">null</isNull>,
        TotalStatisticDays=     <isNotNull property="totalStatisticDays">#totalStatisticDays#</isNotNull>   <isNull property="totalStatisticDays">null</isNull>,   
    <dynamic>
        <isNotNull property="unitPrice" prepend=", ">UnitPrice = #unitPrice#</isNotNull>
        <isNotNull property="settlementAnnexNumber" prepend=", ">SettlementAnnexNumber = #settlementAnnexNumber#</isNotNull>
    </dynamic>
    WHERE AccountDataID=#accountDataId#
```

to Mybatis version 3.2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can look here - http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html

By the way, you don't need code like

`<isNotNull property="statisticAccountingUnits">#statisticAccountingUnits#</isNotNull>   <isNull property="statisticAccountingUnits">null</isNull>`

use #{statisticAccountingUnits, jdbcType=NUMERIC}
http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Parameters

> The JDBC Type is required by JDBC for all nullable columns, if null is
>   passed as a value. You can investigate this yourself by reading the
>   JavaDocs for the PreparedStatement.setNull() method.